# Сложное расположение элементов, flexbox

Tags: css

Есть несколько элементов, которые визуально нужно расположить в несколько "столбцов", друг под другом. Вот пример:

HTML:

```
<div class = "a">
  <div class = "b">1</div>
  <div class = "b">2 (под этот)</div>
  <div class = "b">3 (этот)</div>
  <div class = "b">4</div>
  <div class = "b">5</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.b {
  width: 240px;
  min-width: 240px;
  max-width: 240px;
  height: 145px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.b:nth-child(1) {
  height: 300px;
}
```

Вот ссылка на пример: https://jsfiddle.net/uspeazz4/3/

Каким образом можно элемент под номером `3` поместить ниже элемента под номером `2`, в пустое пространство под ним? Можно ли сделать это, не меняя "нумерацию" элементов и не создавая "вокруг" них оберток, имитирующих "столбцы"?

Comment: что имеете ввиду под _не меняя "нумерацию" элементов_?

Comment: @Grundy, чтобы 4 встал на место 3, а 5 - на место 4.

Comment: вот это похоже на то что вы хотите? https://jsfiddle.net/rx15q58n/

Comment: Что-то маловато флексебоксовских свойст. У меня так ими всё утыкано. А у Вас только 2 и все в элементе контейнере. Подозрительно